# How to change the date format of the input parameters in jaspersoft report (with class type java.util.date) from MM/DD/YY to DD/MM/YY

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a jasperreport with datefrom ,dateto, rundate as input parameters.Class type java.util.date. I want to change date format to DD/MM/YY from MM/DD/YY.So what changes do i need to do?

Comment: Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class

Comment: @AlexK, it does not seem to be about formatting output (change format of input parameter??)... lets see.. maybe unclear...

Comment: @AlexK To tell the truth i think it is related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35083795/create-a-calendar-to-pick-dates-and-time-in-jasper-server, maybe vanj can shed some light?

Comment: In studio I found the pattern changing properties in text field for date which helps change date format.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the xml view and try something like this:

```
  new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/YY").format($P{datefrom})
```

Comment: I tried it but doesnt affect the date. Still the same default format.