# Create a calendar to pick dates (and time) in Jasper server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0sgy.png)
@jtsnr --This snapshot from jasper server.I clicked outside the text box Dateto and a calendar is displayed. But there is no calendar icon outside the boxes as seen in previous example. Also, the text box takes any text typed into it but throws error that type a valid date.If date is typed it accepts it.I want it should accept only dates picked from calendar or typed dates only. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the input control in JasperServer via the wizard you need to select a Type of Date at the Set the Datatype Kind and Properties stage.

Comment: I used the wizard for input control and I am getting the calendar without icon.When I click outside the text box the calendar gets displayed. How do I get direct drop down with visible icon. Another question the date text box takes any text when typed, which should not accept .I want it to take only valid values dates.Is it possible?

Comment: I am not sure how you are getting a calendar displayed if you do not have a calendar icon to click. Can you provide a screenshot of this? The standard behaviour of the input textbox in JRS is to allow any characters but to display an error when the report is run. You would need to customise the source code if you want it to prevent invalid characters from being entered